# Cannot check and handle null value using Play and Scala

Tags: json, api, scala, playframework-2.0, automated-tests

I am trying to build an API endpoint test using Scala and the Play framework.

The code results in an error as I am unable to verify if the response.json is empty. This particular endpoint does not return anything and I need check for such a case.

```
  protected def apiResponse[T](response: Response)(implicit reads: Reads[T]): JsResult[T] = {
    response.status match {
      case Success(code)  => Json.fromJson[T](response.json)
      case ClientError(code) => throw ApiError(response.body, response.status)
      case _ =>  throw ApiError(response.statusText, response.status)
    }
  }
```

I am trying to do something of this sort.

```
protected def apiResponse[T](response: Response)(implicit reads: Reads[T]): JsResult[T] = {
    response.status match {
      case Success(code)  => if(Json.fromJson[T](response.json).equals(JsNull)) Json.fromJson[T](JsString(response.statusText.toString+"1")) else Json.fromJson[T](response.json)
      case ClientError(code) => throw ApiError(response.body, response.status)
      case _ =>  throw ApiError(response.statusText, response.status)
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get this done. What I realized was that the endpoint returned an empty response.body.

if(response.body.toString == "") did the trick for me instead of considering the value of the entire response.json.

Please do let me know i case someone has a better way.